# Force Overwrite Existing Branch missing from TortoiseGit push dialogue

Tags: git, push, tortoisegit

I am used to amending a commit in TortoiseGit then checking the *Force Overwrite Existing Branch (May discard changes)* check box in the Push window. But now that check box is missing from the Push window. How can I force push in TortoiseGit now?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you use TGit 1.8.10+

There are 2 force push checkboxes in Push Dialog.
The left one is the new one (--force-with-lease), which is a "safer" way to force push.
If your local refs/remotes/origin/master == server's master, then you can force push using this option. If someone changed server's master, your local refs/remotes/origin/master != server's master, then you cannot force push using this option.

The right one is the traditional one (--force), which always discard things.

Your git version is below 1.8.5
So --force-with-lease is unavailable.
You only have traditional --force option on the right checkbox.

You may consider to upgrade your git version.

Ref: https://tortoisegit.org/issue/2285

Comment: Why this answer was downvoted? - It's perfectly describing the answer.

Comment: I understand the checkboxes are called "known changes" and "unknown changes" (on the same line as "Force: May discard"

Comment: @MrTux It'd be soooo lovely if it used the text on the checkboxes rather than left and right ones! (IMO)

Answer (score 11):

[image]

Cite source: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-push.html#id692368

> **known changes** - This allows remote repository to
>   accept a safer non-fast-forward push. This can cause the remote
>   repository to lose commits; use it with care. This can prevent from
>   losing unknown changes from other people on the remote. It checks if
>   the server branch points to the same commit as the remote-tracking
>   branch (known changes). If yes, a force push will be performed.
>   Otherwise it will be rejected. Since git does not have remote-tracking
>   tags, tags cannot be overwritten using this option. This passes
>   --force-with-lease option of git push command.
>
> **unknown changes** - This allows remote repository to
>   accept an unsafe non-fast-forward push. This can cause the remote
>   repository to lose commits; use it with care. This does not check any
>   server commits, so it is possible to lose unknown changes on the
>   remote. Use this option with Include Tags to overwrite tags. This
>   passes the traditional --force option of git push command.